# Use UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton in uitextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField which needs to show a button in its right view.

How can I load a button with the same image that the info icon used in UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton?

Comment: You have to create your own image that looks like what you want.

Comment: Drag a UIButton in and in the attribute inspector select its type to be Detail Disclosure.

Comment: I am not ussing xib or storyboard, @RoryMcKinnel

Comment: `UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rory McKinnel explained in the comments, the solution is:

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

Answer (score 0):

//Say this is your text field

```
UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]init];
```

//This is how you add your info button

```
UIButton *yourButton = UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
txt.rightView = yourButton;
txt.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[self.view addSubview:txt];
```